VBA #NA Requesting Data Trying to pull data from BBG
I've been running into the BBG Add-in "NA Requesting Data" issue when building a button that takes data from BBG, takes the inverse of them, and inputs into the cell F16 and G16.
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim inversePairTicker As String
    Dim bidValue As Double
    Dim askValue As Double
    Dim invBidValue As Double
    Dim invAskValue As Double
    inversePairTicker = Range("E13").Value

    If inversePairTicker = "" Then
          Range("F16").Formula  = "=BDP(E9 & "" BGN Curncy"", ""RQ002"")"
          Range("G16").Formula = "=BDP(E9 & "" BGN Curncy"", ""RQ004"")"
    Else
          With Worksheets("Inv Pair Calc")
               .Range("E4").Formula = "=BDP(""" & inversePairTicker & " BGN Curncy"", ""RQ002"")"
               .Range("F4").Formula = "=BDP(""" & inversePairTicker & " BGN Curncy"", ""RQ004"")"

               bidValue = .Range("E4").Value
               askValue = .Range("F4").Value

               invBidValue = 1 / askValue
               invAskValue = 1 / bidValue

           End With

           Range("F16").Value = invBidValue
           Range("G16").Value = invAskValue
    End If
End Sub

My E4 and F4 cells in Inv Pair Calc sometimes give rise to #NA Requesting Data, which stopped the flow of the code. I have to exit the error page, click the refresh button on bloomberg addin to actually get the data from BBG and fill it into E4 and F4 (remove the NA error). And I have click this command button again in order to populate my target cell F16 and G16. Any idea how to fix it?
I've confirmed with BBG that there's nothing wrong with the add-in. Thank you!

The BDP formula is asynchronous, so it may or it may not update immediately. You need to delay the reading part (bidValue = .Range("E4").Value) using Application.OnTime. There are a few similar questions on Stackoverflow. Alternatively (better), use the VBA API instead of relying on formulas. It's more complex to use but more robust.

As per @assylias's suggestion to use the VBA API, I am including some basic example code for a synchronous BDP as it seems to be a common question.
This is delivered as-is: there is minimal error checking and exception handling (exercise for the reader). The function returns one field for one security. The underlying API will accept multiple securities and multiple fields, which can be parsed from the Response (again exercise for the reader).
The same basic structure is valid for BDH and BDS calls but these require different request and response handling.
Option Explicit

'Use Tools | References to include "Bloomberg API COM 3.5 Type Library"
'
'C# Reference: https://bloomberg.github.io/blpapi-docs/dotnet/3.24.4/html/N_Bloomberglp_Blpapi.htm

'Global variables
Private g_session As blpapicomLib2.Session
Private g_servRefData As blpapicomLib2.Service

Private Function bbgConnect() As Boolean
    bbgConnect = False

    If g_session Is Nothing Then
        'Initialize global session
        Set g_session = New blpapicomLib2.Session 'Usually the default Session options work
        
        'Try to start the Bloomberg session
        If g_session.Start Then
            'Acquire the global //blp/refdata service
            bbgConnect = g_session.OpenService("//blp/refdata")
            Set g_servRefData = g_session.GetService("//blp/refdata")
        End If
    Else
        bbgConnect = True
    End If
End Function

Public Function syncBDP(strTicker As String, strField As String) As Variant
    If bbgConnect() Then
        syncBDP = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        
        'Create a request
        Dim req As blpapicomLib2.REQUEST
        Set req = g_servRefData.CreateRequest("ReferenceDataRequest")
        
        'Add the request parameters
        req.Append "securities", strTicker
        req.Append "fields", strField
        
        'Send the request to Bloomberg
        g_session.SendRequest req
        
        Dim bContinue As Boolean
        bContinue = True
        
        Dim evt As blpapicomLib2.Event
        Dim iter As blpapicomLib2.MessageIterator
        Dim eltSecurity As blpapicomLib2.Element
        Dim eltData As blpapicomLib2.Element
        
        'Process the returned events
        While bContinue
            Set evt = g_session.NextEvent
           
            'Only care about RESPONSE events
            If evt.EventType = RESPONSE Then
                Set iter = evt.CreateMessageIterator

                'Iterate through the message, though only expecting one
                While iter.Next
                    'Extract the field result, again only expecting one
                    Set eltSecurity = iter.Message.GetElement("securityData").GetValueAsElement(0)
                    Set eltData = eltSecurity.GetElement("fieldData").GetElement(0)
                    syncBDP = eltData.GetValue(0)
                Wend
            
                'Have the result so break out of loop
                bContinue = False
            End If
        Wend
    Else
        syncBDP = "# No connection to Bloomberg!"
    End If
End Function

Public Sub testBDH()
    Dim v As Variant
    v = syncBDP("EUR Curncy", "PX_LAST")
    Debug.Print v
End Sub

In the spreadsheet:

The reference documentation for the Bloomberg API is here.
